# Set item click event on setOnItemClickListener of listview Android

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have three textviews in a row of a listview using custom adapter and on click of the row, i want to perform the click event of the selected text view.

Below is my sample code for the click event. Here on the first click, the listeners are set and only on the second click the actual click event happens, I want to find this on the first click itself. Is it possible?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,      int pos, long id) {

                    final Order orderBooking = (Order)adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos);

                    // SKU listener
                    final TextView tvSkuId = (TextView) view.findViewById(orderBooking.getSelectedSkuId());
                    tvSkuId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            onSkuClickListener(view, orderBooking);
                        }
                    });

                    // SO listener
                    final TextView tvSoId = (TextView) view.findViewById(orderBooking.getSelectedSoId());
                    tvSoId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            onSoClickListener(view, orderBooking);
                        }
                    });

                    // OR listener
                    final TextView txtOrId = (TextView) view.findViewById(orderBooking.getSelectedOrId());
                    //onOrClickListener(view, orderBooking);
                    txtOrId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            onOrClickListener(view, orderBooking);
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just set those clickListeners in time of initialization? You should make it in your Adapter, when you bind your data to the views. Your code is wrong, cause it will initialize your views every time the user clicks a list's row.

Comment: Yes you are right, I did that way because i created my adapter in a separate class and was unable to update the activity views, now i added the adapter as a subclass and it works perfectly if i set the listener in the adapter itself. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in your adapater, in the getview method. Set an onclick listner for every text view.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    List<SectionObj> article = (List<SectionObj>) children.get(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.listchildlayout_galleryview, null);
    }       
     Gallery gallery = (Gallery) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customviewgallery);
     gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(context, article, groupPosition ));
     gallery.setOnItemClickListener(mOnGalleryClick);

    return convertView;
}

private OnItemClickListener mOnGalleryClick = new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


    }       
};
```

The above is for a gallery view. Do the same thing except do it for a textview

Comment: Hi hades you are right..if we write clicklistener for textview in listView.setOnItemClickListener first list item get clickble after that textview..if we write in adapter..it directly to perticular textview..   thanks.

Comment: I added it in the getView method and its working fine now once i added the adapter as a subclass.

Comment: @Swarna Addeded adapter as a subclass to what? If you need refresh Activity or Fragment listviews you may call notifyDataSetChanged() on base adapter  
`thats notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.`